# Multiple delegates for a table view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Hi I've been googling and I can't find an answer and maybe there's a different way to do this So I'm putting it to the community.

I have a tableview in a UIViewController. The UIViewController is the datasource and delegate for the table view. I then have a second controller which reacts to scrolling in the main UIViewController. Ideally I'd want the second controller to also be a delegate so that scrollviewDidBeginScrolling will fire in both controllers. I want to do this because it makes controller 2 very easy to implement because you'd set it as the delegate and pass in the tableview reference and it would do all the heavy lifting.

Basically can you pass an array of delegates to tableView.delegate? I could see a few situations where you'd want multiple controllers or views to react to an event like scrollViewDidBeginScrolling. Is there any way to accomplish something similar without having to do stuff like

```
-(void)scrollViewDidBeginScrolling:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
     [anotherViewController scrollviewDidScroll:scrollview];
     [otherView scrollViewDidScroll:scrollview];
}
```

I'm using it for a controller than handles Pull To Refresh for tableviews and I want to make implementation as easy as possible with as few lines/methods in the tableview controller as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you need but you will need to chain the delegates. The table view will only have one delegate but you can define your own custom delegate method in the view controller that is the delegate of the tableview and have your other view controller set itself to be the delegate of that. Another brute force method would be to just send out notifications and have the view controllers register for the notification.

Answer (score 1):

In you UIViewController1 delegate methods, just send the same call to UIViewController2 delegate methods. E.I.:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [delegate2 tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   // etc...
```

---

Edit for comment below. You could subclass UITableView and give it multiple delegate properties or an array of delegates property.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   for(id delegate in _delegates)
       [delegate tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   // Do nothing else, because the delegates handle everything.
}
```

Comment: Ya I just didn't want the user to have to add these methods to get the ViewController2 to work. I'm not a big fan of multi method implementations of custom classes because then developer have to make sure they have all the required methods and that they don't conflict with existing methods. This answer will work just not how I want it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is delegate multiplexing. I wrote a class to do just this: https://github.com/aleph7/MultiDelegate